# Load user control into placeholder System.Web.HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, master-pages

I have a UserControl containing a RadGrid and a few other things, that I would like to load into an ASPX page that references a master page.  Whenever I try to load the UserControl into a `<asp:content>` tag, I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

But there aren't any code blocks in the control!

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: Yes, do you have javascript on the page?

Comment: @paqogomez I had javascript in the control but I removed it.  There is javascript in the master page, none in the aspx page itself.

Comment: Your problem is probably the javascript in the master page.  Check out [these](http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-i-e-lt-gt-8ee29b8b5701) [links](http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-error)

Comment: Well that was unexpected.  Wrapping the javascript in RadCodeBlocks fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: I've fought that error a couple of times.  I agree its totally confusing and unexpected.  Glad its working for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript that has `<%%>` code blocks in it in the Master page will cause this error.

The solution is to make sure that your javascript is encapsulated in RadCodeBlocks:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock id="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
  <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js") %>" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

[From Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-i-e-lt-gt-8ee29b8b5701)